# Split an R polygon object into smaller polygons with lines as borders (terra::split doesn't do what I want)

Tags: r, spatial, terra

I realize this is quite similar to some questions that are already out there but I think what I'm looking for is slightly different (and many existing questions are answered with old / out of date software).

I'm using R 4.3.1 on Windows 11 and am working on some spatial data with the terra package (version 1.7-39). I have loaded in a polygon as a SpatVector (it's just one big polygon) as well as another SpatVector with some lines (to give you an idea, the polygon represents a spatial region and the lines represent roads). I want to divide the polygon up into many smaller polygons using the lines as borders. A quick google search reveals that the terra package has a function called `split` that claims to do this, but when I run it, it doesn't give me exactly what I want. I've provided a minimal working example below using some of the example terra spatial data:

```
library(terra)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))[1:5,] 
line <- vect(matrix(c(5.79, 6.22, 5.75, 6.1, 5.8, 
                      50.14, 50.05, 49.88, 49.85, 49.71), ncol=2), "line")
s <- split(v, line)

# If you'd like to visualize what I describe below
plot(s, col = hsv(seq(1, 9, length.out = 9) / 9, 1, 1))
```

The `line` object produces a few line segments that divide `v` into three separate regions (this can be verified using the final line of the example above), but weirdly, the top and bottom region are considered the same polygon, even though they don't actually touch each other. Basically, I want a version of `s` that has three polygons rather than two. Let me know if you have any ideas. I also recognize that the sf package may have a solution but it's not something I'm very familiar with; either way, happy to hear it. Thank you in advance.